# How to convert row values as column names and same column names as column values in python?

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

I want to convert row values as column names and those column names would be the column values. I have tried with pivot but it is not giving desired output.

```
Data:
col1   col2   col3 col4
x1      y1      z1   a1
x1      y1      z1    a2
x1      y1      z1    a3
```

I have tried like below:

```
Data.pivot(columns='Col4', values='col4')

Output:
a1  a2   a3
a1 NAN   NAN
NAN a2   NAN
NAN  NAN  a3
```

```
Desired output:

col1 col2 col3  a1  a2 a3
x1     y1   z1  a1  a2 a3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `pivot`, but you need to specify the `index` argument to keep your "col1", "col2", "col3". Once you do that, you can clean up the dataframe a little bit to get the result you want.

```
out = (df.pivot(index=["col1", "col2", "col3"], columns="col4", values="col4")
         .rename_axis(columns=None)
         .reset_index())

print(out)
  col1 col2 col3  a1  a2  a3
0   x1   y1   z1  a1  a2  a3
```

Steps

- `pivot(...)`: pivot the dataframe as desired. This makes a `MultiIndex` of "col1", "col2", and "col3". Then the actual columns & values from the value of "col4"
- `rename_axis(columns=None)`: `pivot` makes a columns an `Index` object with a name. I find that this name throws people off be adjusting how the dataframe is represented. Here I remove the name from the column `Index` so that it can be represented how OP expects
- `reset_index()` as stated earlier- `pivot` makes a `MultiIndex` of "col1", "col2", and "col3". We use `reset_index()` here to take these values and insert it into the actual data of the `DataFrame` instead of being a `MultiIndex`